# How to start/stop/restart mongod on windows

Tags: mongodb

I've 3 mongodb instances running on same machine with different ports, How do I start/stop/restart each one's mongod process depending his port/db path?
I've tried to mongod --shutdown but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
net stop <service name>
net start <service name>
```

The service you can set in the configuration file, e.g. :

```
processManagement:
  windowsService:
    serviceName: MongoDB_Config_2
    displayName: MongoDB Config 2
    description: MongoDB Config Server Replica Set - 2 


net stop MongoDB_Config_2
net start MongoDB_Config_2
```

Comment: So for each mongodb instance I change his configuration file under  "processManagement"? Why when I run net stop Mongodb I get "System error 5 has occurred."?

Comment: Did you create the service? Could be done with `mongod.exe --config c:\MongoDB\config\mongocfg_1.cfg --install` for example

Comment: I can see MongoDB on services.msc with "path to executeable: 'mongod.exe --config c:\MongoDB\config\mongocfg_1.cfg --service' . on the config file "processManagement" isn't configured and marked with #. What do i need to do?

Comment: See [Windows Service Options](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/index.html#processManagement.windowsService.serviceName): *Default: MongoDB* - However you cannot run 3 services having all the same name.